# Button in tree view odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I need a button in tree view for all line. After clicking on the button I need get line id.

I'm trying, but not working:

***.xml**

```xml
<button name="copy_line" class="text-right" icon="fa-files-o" type="object"/>
```

***.py**

```py
@api.multi
def copy_line(self):
     print("Not come here!")
     for r in self:
        print(r.id)
```

`object has no attribute 'copy_line'`

Comment: is it same model for which you wrote this method and tree view?

Comment: @VikiChavada  yes...

Comment: Which tree view are you trying to change? Invoice or Sale?

Comment: @ManuW. I want add buton in my custom module. On button click I need line id, after get id I want create new line.

Comment: can you please show us your full tree view and py with model name?

Comment: @VikiChavada  In other module work fine  --> https://ibb.co/iyRC95  My example is correct! I must review other module and find where is problem.

Comment: @Pointer You should include your full view and model definitions. That being said, I don't understand the point of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To call the method on button click that record should be saved.
But in this case, Record was not saved so you are not able to call the method on button click.

Alternet way is, you can create a new line based on onchange or button in the footer and add self._cr.commit() to commit and raise ValidationError.

Answer (score 0):

You define `copy_line` in the wrong model.
If your `button` is included inside a tree view defined for a `One2Many` field `line_ids` and that field is referencing `object.line`, you method `copy_line` should be created in that model.

For example:

```py
    line_ids = fields.One2Many('object.line', 'ref_id', string='Lines')

class ObjectLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'object.line'  

    @api.multi
    def copy_line(self):
        print("Not come here!")
        for r in self:
            print(r.id)
```